# ImageView not loading image from resources folder when deployed as DMG

Tags: java, imageview, scenebuilder, dmg, efxclipse

Im having some trouble, Im using e(fx)clipse and scene builder with java as my language and have developed a desktop app (mysql).  I have built the file with fxbuild (ant) and exported as a dmg, however whenever i have run the programme on a different workstation the images are all missing.

For the images I have not used css, they have been linked through scenbuilder to a resources folder located in the project root(with src/bin etc)

I have tried using absolute relative/document relative and classpath imageview path settings on scene builder all to know avail, if anyone may asist it would be gratly apprecaited:)

Comment: Though, I am not sure, how helpful this thread be, regarding how to [add images to Java Project](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9866659/1057230), though a similar approach for your case can do the trick, I guess. Please do have a look. And moreover, do provide, some extra information, as to how the code is trying to access the images, some info on directory structure. If possible, add some links to external source for images showing directory structure